# what it means when we see something like static1.site.com

Tags: subdomain

I've seen this issue so much, what it means?
what is its usage? is it just a simple subdomain or not?
It seems that sites with lots of visitors use that!
Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated...
The example site for example is as below:

```
http://static1.cloob.com
```

thanks,
alireza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a performance optimization practice.

Your server must include a cookie for EVERY HTTP request it receives. That means if your site serves 500 images on the page - the server will send back 500 cookies. That's obviously bad and slow. That's why separate domains and sub-domains used to serve static content (images, stylesheets, flash movies etc.) from a cookieless domain.

Read a little more here, for example - [*Serving Static Content from a Cookieless Domain*](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/)

Answer (score 3):

It is a simple subdomain.

Using multiple subdomains for static content allows you to avoid the browser's max-connections-per-server limit.